# Create a real chat application between 2 clients or more

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I have a web application that I have created with angularJS/Symfony2 and a mobile app with(ionic) I want to create a real chat application between this 2 clients.I thought to use nodeJS and websockets??I can have many clients conncted from their mobile
I have read many articles about firebase for angularJS and redis,but I don't know from where I will start
have you please any idea how can I do that
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to start is check basic chat solution on NodeJs http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Also as alternative you can use Rachet(WebSockets for PHP) http://socketo.me/ to get more closer integration with Symfony2

Comment: thanks @Evgeniy Kuzmin,I want to let symfony2 for all database traitment and nodeJS for real time communciation,but the problem how can I send the history of communciation from nodeJS to symfony2

Comment: Look at this answer to have some more hints : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16231521/4074148

Comment: you can use Redis as data storage/spool for Symfony https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

Answer (score 1):

You can definetely use node and socket.io.

Start here:
http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

To integrate it with angular, you can use this module:
https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io